# Make every second row in a column NA

Tags: r

I want to make every second row NA in column q2, any suggestions on how I accomplish this? Thanks!

```
id <- rep(1:5, each=3)
trt <- rep(LETTERS[1:3],5)
set.seed(1)
q1 <- runif(15)
set.seed(2)
q2 <- runif(15)
set.seed(3)
q3 <- runif(15)


df <- data.frame(id,trt,q1,q2,q3)


df
   id trt         q1        q2        q3
1   1   A 0.26550866 0.1848823 0.1680415
2   1   B 0.37212390 0.7023740 0.8075164
3   1   C 0.57285336 0.5733263 0.3849424
4   2   A 0.90820779 0.1680519 0.3277343
5   2   B 0.20168193 0.9438393 0.6021007
6   2   C 0.89838968 0.9434750 0.6043941
7   3   A 0.94467527 0.1291590 0.1246334
8   3   B 0.66079779 0.8334488 0.2946009
9   3   C 0.62911404 0.4680185 0.5776099
10  4   A 0.06178627 0.5499837 0.6309793
11  4   B 0.20597457 0.5526741 0.5120159
12  4   C 0.17655675 0.2388948 0.5050239
13  5   A 0.68702285 0.7605133 0.5340354
14  5   B 0.38410372 0.1808201 0.5572494
15  5   C 0.76984142 0.4052822 0.8679195
>
```

...............................................
...............................................

Answer (score 4):

Use R's *recycling* (of a shorter-vector to a longer-vector):

```r
df$q2[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- NA
df
#    id trt     q1    q2    q3
# 1   1   A 0.2655 0.185 0.168
# 2   1   B 0.3721    NA 0.808
# 3   1   C 0.5729 0.573 0.385
# 4   2   A 0.9082    NA 0.328
# 5   2   B 0.2017 0.944 0.602
# 6   2   C 0.8984    NA 0.604
# 7   3   A 0.9447 0.129 0.125
# 8   3   B 0.6608    NA 0.295
# 9   3   C 0.6291 0.468 0.578
# 10  4   A 0.0618    NA 0.631
# 11  4   B 0.2060 0.553 0.512
# 12  4   C 0.1766    NA 0.505
# 13  5   A 0.6870 0.761 0.534
# 14  5   B 0.3841    NA 0.557
# 15  5   C 0.7698 0.405 0.868
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this using `tidyverse` functions along with a conditional to evaluate modulus values according to row number. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
rm(list=ls())
id <- rep(1:5, each=3)
trt <- rep(LETTERS[1:3],5)
set.seed(1)
q1 <- runif(15)
set.seed(2)
q2 <- runif(15)
set.seed(3)
q3 <- runif(15)
df <- data.frame(id,trt,q1,q2,q3)
#Code
df <- df %>% mutate(q2=ifelse(row_number()%%2==0,NA,q2))
```

Output:

```
   id trt         q1        q2        q3
1   1   A 0.26550866 0.1848823 0.1680415
2   1   B 0.37212390        NA 0.8075164
3   1   C 0.57285336 0.5733263 0.3849424
4   2   A 0.90820779        NA 0.3277343
5   2   B 0.20168193 0.9438393 0.6021007
6   2   C 0.89838968        NA 0.6043941
7   3   A 0.94467527 0.1291590 0.1246334
8   3   B 0.66079779        NA 0.2946009
9   3   C 0.62911404 0.4680185 0.5776099
10  4   A 0.06178627        NA 0.6309793
11  4   B 0.20597457 0.5526741 0.5120159
12  4   C 0.17655675        NA 0.5050239
13  5   A 0.68702285 0.7605133 0.5340354
14  5   B 0.38410372        NA 0.5572494
15  5   C 0.76984142 0.4052822 0.8679195
```

Or maybe indexing with a sequence:

```
#Code 2
index <- seq(2,nrow(df),by=2)
#Replace
df$q2[index] <- NA
```

Output:

```
   id trt         q1        q2        q3
1   1   A 0.26550866 0.1848823 0.1680415
2   1   B 0.37212390        NA 0.8075164
3   1   C 0.57285336 0.5733263 0.3849424
4   2   A 0.90820779        NA 0.3277343
5   2   B 0.20168193 0.9438393 0.6021007
6   2   C 0.89838968        NA 0.6043941
7   3   A 0.94467527 0.1291590 0.1246334
8   3   B 0.66079779        NA 0.2946009
9   3   C 0.62911404 0.4680185 0.5776099
10  4   A 0.06178627        NA 0.6309793
11  4   B 0.20597457 0.5526741 0.5120159
12  4   C 0.17655675        NA 0.5050239
13  5   A 0.68702285 0.7605133 0.5340354
14  5   B 0.38410372        NA 0.5572494
15  5   C 0.76984142 0.4052822 0.8679195
```

Comment: Two thoughts: (1) If you're already in `dplyr`, I recommend `if_else`, it's type-safe and doesn't destroy `class` (in some types) like base's `ifelse` does. (2) Because of this, it's sometimes annoying to have to use "real" typed `NA`, e.g., `NA_real_` ... in those cases, it's possible to index the vector with `NA` to get the perfect match, i.e., `if_else(..., q2[NA], q2)`.

Comment: @r2evans Great suggestion !!! I will start to apply it ! Many infinite thanks :)

Comment: (I've been bitten by this so many times with `POSIXt` that I now have a `POSIX_NA` variable defined in some of my packages, created with `Sys.time()[NA]`. Another reason I've been using `replace` more than `ifelse` when easy, as it does not lose `class` like `ifelse` does.)

Comment: @r2evans You give great suggestions. And sometimes `replace` can be better and classic conditionals.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
> df$q2[seq(2,nrow(df), 2)] <- NA
> df
   id trt         q1        q2        q3
1   1   A 0.26550866 0.1848823 0.1680415
2   1   B 0.37212390        NA 0.8075164
3   1   C 0.57285336 0.5733263 0.3849424
4   2   A 0.90820779        NA 0.3277343
5   2   B 0.20168193 0.9438393 0.6021007
6   2   C 0.89838968        NA 0.6043941
7   3   A 0.94467527 0.1291590 0.1246334
8   3   B 0.66079779        NA 0.2946009
9   3   C 0.62911404 0.4680185 0.5776099
10  4   A 0.06178627        NA 0.6309793
11  4   B 0.20597457 0.5526741 0.5120159
12  4   C 0.17655675        NA 0.5050239
13  5   A 0.68702285 0.7605133 0.5340354
14  5   B 0.38410372        NA 0.5572494
15  5   C 0.76984142 0.4052822 0.8679195
```